# Question about basis of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Let $V$ be a vector space and $\dim(V) = n$. Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ and $\operatorname{rank}(T) = 2$. Suppose $r_1, r_2$ are the linear independent rows, prove that there exist bases $β, γ$ of V so that $r_1, r_2$ are the last two rows of $T_{\beta\gamma}$ and other rows of the matrix are zero.

I know that if $\operatorname{rank}T = 2$, there would be exactly two independent rows in the matrix and by doing some row operations (i.e multiplying the initial matrix by some elementary matrices), we can get the matrix such that $r_1, r_2$ are the last two rows and all others rows are zero while preserving the rank of the matrix. My question is that how can I prove there exist two bases that would satisfy those conditions from the linear operator that has been given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two matrices of the same size are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence) if and only if they have the same rank.

Since the matrix $U$ with all zeroes except for the two last rows, which are linearly independent rows taken from $T$, is itself of rank $2$, just like $T$, you know the two matrices are equivalent. Hence, there are invertible matrices $Q$ and $P$ such that
$$
U = Q^{-1} T P.
$$
Collect the columns of $P$ in one basis and the columns of $Q$ in the other.

---

Your observation already let's you pick $P$ to be the identity matrix since you didn't need any column operations, so one basis can stay the standard basis. The matrix $Q^{-1}$ is then given by the row operations you described.

Comment: I understand that T and U are equivalent and we can get the expression like above. The matrix Q is basically the product of the elementary matrices from row operations. Moreover, there is no column operation so P is the identity matrix. But can you clarify on how we can derive the basis from such invertible matrices?

Comment: @Harry Transform $T$ to $U$ using row operations. Do the same row operations on the identity matrix to obtain $Q^{-1}$. Take the inverse of that matrix to obtain $Q$ itself. (Alternatively apply the inverse row operations in reverse order to the identity matrix to obtain $Q$ directly.) The columns of that form the desired basis of the codomain.

Comment: I forgot to add into the question that the bases beta and gamma is the bases of the vector space V. If the bases in this case is not the bases of F_n but the bases of V, would it make any difference?